Help Identifying locked toggle switch's purpose
I have been investigating the wiring in my attic (1920's construction, 1990's? re-wiring) and cannot understand the purpose of a handy box with a locked toggle switch. The Circuit controls a 1/2 HP whole house fan as well as one outlet. Both are downstream of this switch. As is visible in the picture there is a knockout missing and the box is not properly secured to the post, nor is the box properly grounded. I would like to tidy things up and secure it better but want to understand the purpose of this switch before I do so.
The toggle switches the "hot" conductor, it is connected to the hots via two short sranded yellow wire sections and two slightly longer solid 12 gauge sections (one white one black).
If the toggle was supposed to function as a safety shutoff when people are working around the attic fan I can't understand if why it would be locked into the "on" position. Additionally, I cannot find any capacitors that might be trying to do some kind of suppression.


Is it where people would have to brush against it?

I suppose you could brush against it, but you would have to step across exposed rafters and the ceiling fan itself.
And there is no way to disable the lock without opening the handy box cover.

I suspect you can loosen a nut we can't see behind the screwhead we can see to allow the lock to slide off the toggle without opening the box.

It was a clever sparky that put that together. Maybe a little too clever.

If you just pulled the arm outward, would it clear the toggle (allowing you to flip the switch)?

Resolutions go in the answer box.

@keshlam I have a wire tracker/outlet tester combo which wasn't very expensive. It only works on live lines, though. It's a pretty useful tool for old wiring where the goal seems to have been to make a circuit run through as many rooms as possible.

Please take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

That may be a fire-safety device known as a fusible link. The idea is that the linkage bar is 2 pieces held together with a low-melting point solder. In case of fire that solder melts and releases the switch to turn off. In this case, that would shut off the fan so that it doesn't contribute to the spread of the fire.
If you remove the linkage and discover that the switch is spring-return to the "off" position, that would be strong evidence for this.

Brilliant.   A home-made this.   Completely reverses my assessment of the person who made it.

This is it. The linkage has a UL stamp on it, and after clearing I can make out 165 degrees

It can be "unlocked" with a screwdriver, evidently, so it's just making sure it's only turned off deliberately. You could replace with with a standard pull-out type disconnect if desired.
Or remove the "lock" (and plug the open hole, and put in a proper ground screw, and screw it in place properly) and see if any attic residents you might prefer not to have switch it off for you.
But in that case I don't think it meets the requirements for a safety disconnect in sight of the hardwired equipment, unless it can be locked "off"; And a standard disconnect (which are inexpensive, really, if at overkill amperages for this job, typically) is both more obvious in intent and more definitely lockable as OFF.

A screwdriver would be messy, since those don't look like captive nuts. I'd say that it can be "unlocked" simply by lifting the springy retainer over the end of the switch actuator, i.e. it's "think what you're doing" rather than "don't do this".

I'm convinced the other answer is correct, it's not a disconnect, it's not meant to be released, it's a home-made version of a fusible link (expensive commercially) that pops open when hot so the fan doesn't accelerate the fire.

Best suggestion I have is to follow the wires and figure out what they are connected to.
A wire tracing device will make this easier, letting you follow the wire where it isn't visible. Basic versions are starting to be available at reasonable prices. I've successfully used a circuit-breaker-finder to trace a wire, but that requires the circuit be live.
